# Windows Server 2008R2 Print server, access by CNAME not working

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, network-printer

I am trying to alias my print server to \\printserver.  The actual name of the server is \\fileserver1 and/or \\fileserver2.  The idea is that I can switch the CNAME between each real server as required.

I am able to connect to a printer on \\printserver\Printer Name, however \\printserver.fqdn.com\Printer Name gives me an error "Operation could not be completed (error 0x0..0709). Double check the printer name and make sure that the printer is connected to the network.".

I am able to access the printers on each server directly, either using the netbios name for FQDN name.  The issue only arises when using the FQDN CNAME.

The DnsOnWire registry key has been applied (see https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2546625/en-us).

The registry change to LanmanServer has also been applied (see https://support.microsoft.com/kb/281308 as it applies to Server 2003).

I have applied the setspn commands as defined on http://www.md3v.com/enable-windows-server-smb-2-0-alias-cname%29

I can browse to \\printserver.fqdn.com and see the printers and shares.

All hosts are on a flat network, and are all behind a firewall...  I don't have any reasons to suspect any interference from there.

Any help, direction, suggestions are all appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: [Does this Technet blog post help you out at all](http://blogs.technet.com/b/supportingwindows/archive/2013/04/23/unable-to-connect-to-a-printer-using-a-cname-record.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the registry keys I've used on Windows 2008 print servers that seems to always work for me:

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA\MSV1_0
BackConnectionHostNames - REG_MULTI_SZ
Data: Should be the NetBIOS name of the new server and also the old server. Example SERVER1 SERVER2

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print
DnsOnWire - REG_DWORD
Data: 1

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters
OptionalNames - REG_MULTI_SZ
Data: Should be the NetBIOS name of the new server and also the old server. Example SERVER1 SERVER2

After setting the three above registry entries, I usually reboot the server.

Answer (score 0):

Problem can be within active directory. Remove and rejoin the servers to the domain can fix the issue.